# How to format date picker on salesforce1?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I created a VF page for Mobile. This page contains input field Opportunity close date.

I am facing issue the way the calendar is showing only on mobile as shown below.

[image: screen shot of date picker on Mobile:]

Can any one please tell me how to format this ?

I tried below code but it is not updating the close date when I save (It is not taking any other date)

```
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}" type="date" />

<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save" />
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue...Have you solved it?